# Find all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the given matrix in C

Tags: c, algorithm, eigenvalue, svd, eigenvector

I would need to write the SVD algorithm that requires the calculation of all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix, so i ask you if any of could indicate a code useful for their calculation. Doing it on paper is simple but on the code side, things get hard.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you already have an algorithm/ pseudo-code in mind ? Would you mind posting that as well with the question ?

Comment: algorithms that calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix are a very advanced mathematics topic, i would really recommend you look into a library like intel-mkl or CBLAS or any other library that implements them, it'll take you months to do so yourself and the result will be very bad, plus people with PHDs have already done the work for you and put them in those libraries.

Comment: specifically the QR method for symmetric matricies is useful in your case, but you have to find a math library that implements it and works with your codebase.

Comment: I need to implement code from scratch without using libraries for a university project.  Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Transform to Hessenberg form, this is mostly like a QR decomposition. Then on the resulting tridiagonal matrix the Householder reflectors have a short length, influence only a small part of the matrix. The best symmetric matrix for SVD is the one of the Golub-Kahan method, starting with the block matrix [[0,  A], [A.T, 0]].

Answer (score 0):

You don't show any algorithm (or even mention the one you are using) so we have to guess everything.

Long time ago, I saw an iterative (and simple) algorithm that allows you to get the largest eigenvalue (and its corresponding eigenvector) by applying the matrix to it, and scaling the vector to a normalized size (being e.g. to make it norm 1.0 or scale it to make 1.0 the first component, etc.)  The paper article stopped here, so I had to struggle my brain to get the others.  But there's a way to continue, just continue reading...

This allows you to get the biggest eigenvalue and also the eigenvector (it can be demonstrated that this sequence makes all the other eigenvectors' components to get smaller and smaller, finally disappearing, leaving only the largest eigenvalue's eigenvector)

now, you have to calculate a matrix projection, that nullifies this vector (by subtracting the component of that vector from the identity matrix) and multiply the resulting matrix by the original one.  You will have a matrix that nullifies the largest eigenvalue's eigenvector and leaves everithing as the original matrix did.  You then repeat the process (this cannot give you the same vector because now the eigenvector is in the kernel of the matrix)  Repeat the process dim-1 times, and you will get all the eigenvectors/eigenvalues of your matrix.

Being the matrix symetric warrants you a good behaviour.

You will have to decide how to normalize your vector, what vector to start with (a random vector is a good chance) how many iterations to use (as the eigenvalues get closer, the convergence speed gets lower)

Put your code in the question, so we can help you.

Comment: The first is called "Power iteration", and is largely superseded by the unshifted QR method. The shifted variants of the QR method converge faster.

Comment: This is the only I know about.  Probably you can illustrate it in a good answer, explaining how it works.

Comment: This would be off-topic here. The shifted QR algorithm can be found in any numerical linear algebra treatment. In times long past this was combined with the Hessenberg form and extended from a linear factor to 4th or higher degree approximate factors of the characteristic polynomial to the multi-shift bulge-chasing algorithms.